# Angular Cli installation Error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

[image]

I am try to install Angular CLI but running into the error above.

Do I need JAVA installed in my machine?

Tried following Commands repeatedly still did not worked.

```
npm cache clear
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli

node -v:
v9.4.0

npm -v:
5.6.0
```

What are the prerequisites to install Angular CLI?

[image]

After all running command prompt as admin did not worked. **Rolling back issue fixed** but still facing the same issue. updated question with the above image.

Comment: Did you try running cmd as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need JAVA to install angular/cli, think you're only seeing this because it's part of environment variable `path` on your computer
2. The current issue you're seeing is fail to install npm package uglifyjs globally in windows,in AppData Roaming directory

> EPRM: operation not premitted, lstat `c:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules...

Most likely because your current user login doesn't have write permission to this directory. So try to open command prompt as admin, which should have write-permission, then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still facing same issue after all running cmd prompt as Admin. I have updated my question.

Comment: @MahanteshKumbar, try again with force flag -f  `npm install -g -f angular-cli`

Comment: @lancovici npm cache clean [<path>]
**aliases:** npm cache clear, npm cache rm

Comment: @MahanteshKumbar, other than trying the npm install with `-f` if you haven't installed anything important globally, i suggest you go to your global npm directory (type %APPDATA% in file explore, and go to npm directory, and delete node_modules), then update node, and npm to latest, and retry

Comment: other than angular-cli i am able install other packages successfully like gulp,grunt,yarn. let me try by uninstalling node and also manually  delete the **npm** and **npm-cache** folder from global directory.